# In Html5 how do I have Image link with text beneath it

Tags: html

In Html how do I have Image link with text beneath it, Ive read about Figure and Figure Caption but that seems to be only for a standalone image not one within an a link.

This is what I currently have, it shows the 470 x 470 text to the bottom left of the image instead of beneath it.

```
<a href="../images/txpvc3LLOvRWy5XLiJE9Zw==.jpg">470 x 470
<img 
src="../images/txpvc3LLOvRWy5XLiJE9Zw==_thumbnail.jpg" 
hspace="4" 
height="100" 
width="100" 
align="top">
</a>
```

Comment: The attributes, hspace and align, within your `<img>` tag are obsolete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<a>` tags around the `figure`.
If you want to centre the text in the caption you'd have to set the figure to `inline-block` and the figcaption to have `text-align: center`

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="demo image" />
    <figcaption>This is an example of a link, it goes nowhere...</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want.

My assumption is you want image and text both should be clickable and align the text to bottom.

Make your `img` as blocked element. So that the text will automatically comes below the image.

```css
.testimg {display:block}
```

```html
<a href="../images/txpvc3LLOvRWy5XLiJE9Zw==.jpg">
<img class="testimg"
src="http://miumosa.com/assets/products/sample-_20170209104115.png" 
hspace="4" 
height="100" 
width="100" 
align="top">470 x 470</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can change the width of `img` if required.

```css
.imgtext {
    text-align: center
    
}

.imgtext img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
   ;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgtext">
    <img src="https://s14.postimg.org/u18a0yc1t/contact-1.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>**Image text** </p>
</div>
```